# Select second front camera on Android device with Agora.io in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, agora.io, agora-implementation

I am using an Android device with **two** front facing cameras and I need to use the Ultra Wide one (that is not the default one use by Agora) for the video chat. How can I accomplish this?
It works just fine with the default front facing camera.

I tried following the documentation for using a custom source here: `https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/develop/custom-video-and-audio?platform=unity`
but was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation was missing a crucial part - getting the image from the camera and pushing that data to Agora server.

```js
    private void Update()
    {
        if (_webCameraTexture == null || !_webCameraTexture.isPlaying) return;

        if (_texture2D == null)
            _texture2D = new Texture2D(_webCameraTexture.width, _webCameraTexture.height);

        Color[] pixels = _webCameraTexture.GetPixels();
        _texture2D.SetPixels(pixels);
        _texture2D.Apply();

        int width = _texture2D.width;
        int height = _texture2D.height;

        // Convert Texture2D to a byte array
        byte[] textureBytes = _texture2D.GetRawTextureData();

        // Create an external video frame
        ExternalVideoFrame externalVideoFrame = new ExternalVideoFrame();
        externalVideoFrame.type = VIDEO_BUFFER_TYPE.VIDEO_BUFFER_RAW_DATA;
        externalVideoFrame.format = VIDEO_PIXEL_FORMAT.VIDEO_PIXEL_RGBA;
        externalVideoFrame.buffer = textureBytes;
        externalVideoFrame.stride = width;
        externalVideoFrame.height = height;
        externalVideoFrame.timestamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000; // Convert to ms

        RtcEngine.PushVideoFrame(externalVideoFrame);
    }
```